# WINAPI - Request not supported for getting the storage information of a USB drive

Tags: c, winapi, usb-drive

I already know the VID and PID of the USB, but I can't seem to access the storage information of the USB drive.

The program outputs a `GetLastError()` code of 50, which corresponds to "The request is not supported."
It should be supported since, I am only trying to get the storage information.

Here is the minimum reproduceable code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <Usbiodef.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <errhandlingapi.h>

HANDLE getUsbHandle(DWORD VID, DWORD PID) {
  HANDLE usb_handle = NULL;

  /* Get all the devices */
  HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
  if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Failed to get device information set\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ifaceData = { 0 };
  ifaceData.cbSize = sizeof(ifaceData);
  DWORD index = 0;

  /* Enumerates over all the devices */
  while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE, index++, &ifaceData)) { 
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *pDetail = NULL;
    DWORD detailSize = 0;

    SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &ifaceData, NULL, 0, &detailSize, NULL); // Finding detail size

    pDetail = (SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *)malloc(detailSize);
    pDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &ifaceData, pDetail, detailSize, NULL, NULL)) {
      printf("Failed to get device interface detail. Error: %i", GetLastError());
      free(pDetail);
      continue;
    }

    DWORD vid, pid;
    sscanf_s(pDetail->DevicePath, "\\\\?\\usb#vid_%04X&pid_%04X#", &vid, &pid); // grab the vid and pid of the device

    if (vid != VID || pid != PID) {
      free(pDetail);
      continue;
    }

    usb_handle = CreateFile(pDetail->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); // create a handle to the USB drive

    if (usb_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
      printf("INVALID HANDLE VALUE: Error: %i\n", GetLastError());
      free(pDetail);
      continue;
    }

    break; // USB which matches VID and PID is found, so break
  }

  SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo); // free unused resources info

  return usb_handle;
}

int main() {
  DWORD VID = 0X090C;
  DWORD PID = 0X1000;

  HANDLE usb_handle = getUsbHandle(VID, PID);

  if (!usb_handle) {
    printf("Null USB handle\n");
    return 1;
  }

  DISK_GEOMETRY_EX diskGeometry; // stores the storage info
  DWORD bytesReturned = 0;

  BOOL result = DeviceIoControl( // get storage info
      usb_handle,
      IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX,
      NULL,
      0,
      &diskGeometry,
      sizeof(diskGeometry),
      &bytesReturned,
      NULL
  );
  if (result == FALSE) {
    printf("Failed to get storage info. Error: %i\n", GetLastError());
    printf("Bytes returned: %i\n", bytesReturned);
    return 2;
  }

  printf("Bytes returned: %i\n", bytesReturned);
  printf("Storage: %llu\n\n", diskGeometry.DiskSize.QuadPart);
}
```

Compiled using `gcc main.c - main.exe -lsetupapi`

Output:

```
Failed to get storage info. Error: 50
Bytes returned: 0
```

50 error code corresponds to "The request is not supported."

Comment: `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY_EX` handled by the **disk** device. but you open another, not disk device. you simply send request to wrong device, which of course not support it

Comment: @RbMm how would I go about getting the storage information of a USB storage drive then? I tried `IOCTL_STORAGE_READ_CAPACITY` with `STORAGE_READ_CAPACITY` as the structure and `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_TELEMETRY` with `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` as the structure. But both returned error code 50.

Comment: but i say - you use wrong device stack. you open *PDO* on *USBHUB3* propably. the *FDO* attached to it, on *USBSTOR*, here already created *PDO* for disk stack - the some *DRx* *FDO* attached to it. you need send IOCTLs to this stack

Comment: [Using the Windows Sysinternals WinObj tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#nt-namespaces) to check if it's the right device. My USB mouse supports the control code.

Comment: @RbMm If you specify the volume / partition name in `CreateFile()` instead of the code I have just used, I am guessing it sends the IOCTL to the FDO, because then the code works.
So what I need to do is get the volumes names from the USB drive using the PID and VID.
Do you have any idea on how I can get the volume names from a USB drive?

Comment: The disk is the child device of the USB device but the volumes are no child of the disk.
To get the volume(s) of a disk you must match the device numbers of both by means of IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, see here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13839/How-to-Prepare-a-USB-Drive-for-Safe-Removal