# Windows - How to get Device Path of USB device via Vendor and Product ID

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw

I am working on a Program that needs to manually issue a USB packet to a specific device.

Since I need a handle for the device to send a control code to the driver, I need to find the Device Path using only the devices Vendor and Product ID.

Thus far I have found the SetupDi* family of functions, but they don't appear to allow me to narrow it down without further information being available, like the Device Instance ID.

Comment: The SetupDi functions are correct, but you have to go the other direction -- enumerate USB devices and filter out the ones with the wrong Vendor or PID.  That's because you can have more than one matching USB device plugged in to a single computer.

Comment: Does the code in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872141/winapi-request-not-supported-for-getting-the-storage-information-of-a-usb-driv work for you?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT that appears to be doing exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the code in [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872141/winapi-request-not-supported-for-getting-the-storage-information-of-a-usb-driv) showed, the [DevicePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/ns-setupapi-sp_device_interface_detail_data_a) consists of Vendor ID and Product ID. You can grab the Vendor ID and Product ID of the device based on the device path and compare them with specified IDs.